# My two younger sisters

Tags: phrase-meaning

Hello everyone:

Let’s say I have two younger sisters named Mary and Stacy, aged 28 and 25 respectively.

In a conversation with a friend of mine, I want to talk about Mary, who is younger than me but older than Stacy. What should I say?

a.     Mary, **the older of my two younger sisters**, is 28 years old.

b.     Mary , **my older younger sister**, is 28 years old.

c.     Mary , **my first younger sister**, is 28 years old.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In all of your sentences, the essential information you are conveying is:

> Mary is 28 years old.

I would rephrase the sentence slightly so the fact that Mary is your younger sister isn't part of the nonrestrictive clause:

> My younger sister Mary, the older of my two sisters, is 28 years old.

This conveys additional essential information—that Mary is your sister and that she's younger than you. (*My younger sister Mary is 28 years old.*)

Additionally, if you look at the logic of what's being conveyed, if Mary is the *older* of your two sisters *and* she's younger than you—then your other sister must also be younger than you. So, you don't need to say that explicitly.